# Knockout not displaying Observable Array?

Tags: knockout.js

```
<h2>Friends</h2>
    <div data-bind="template: 'friendsTemplate'"></div>

        <script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
            <ul>

              {{each friends }}
                <li>${ name }</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>

        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function friend(name) {
            this.name = ko.observable(name);
        }
        var ViewModel = {
            firstName: ko.observable("Chandan"),
            lastName: ko.observable("Khatwani"),
            friends: ko.observableArray([new friend("Amit"), new friend("Altamash")])
        };

        ViewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        }, ViewModel);

        ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
    </script>
```

The Friends List does not get rendered as list

Comment: Do you get any error in your browser's console? Have you referenced jquery and jQuery.tmpl as described in the documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_6_using_jquerytmpl_an_external_stringbased_template_engine? Otherwise your code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/U9QJh/

Comment: I have added the jquery.tmpl file after looking at the documentation. but doesn't work

Comment: After adding the tmpl file, I get a javaruntime error in knockout.js at line 58

Comment: I have never seen the syntax you are using for your foreach loop. What version of KO are you using? Usually I have had to do data-bind='foreach: friends'

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to reference anything other than jQuery and Knockout unless you are using a really old version of Knockout.  There are two solutions to this, with templates or without.

**WITH TEMPLATE**  You just need to use the [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) in the correct way.  Your code should look like this;

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'friendsTemplate', foreach: friends }"></ul>

<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>
```

**WITHOUT TEMPLATE** A simpler approach...

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: friends">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```